# FFmpeg codec frame size is not set and audio longer than video

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I just found out about FFmpeg and I need it to cut loads of MP4 files to the last 20 seconds of each. Each MP4 file has **one video track** and **two audio tracks**.

I've been using this line of code:

```
for %F in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "%F" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~nF_trimmed.mp4"
```

The trimming goes well but there's a problem with the audio. This error appears without canceling the trimming process:

```
[mp4 @ 0000025740443740] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0000025740443740] track 2: codec frame size is not set
```

And when I drop the trimmed files to a video editing software, this can be seen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa0aJ.png

The second audio track is longer than the video track.

Keep in mind that I'm not familiarized with coding and I just need this for video editing purposes only. I've been trying to find a way around but I had no luck. Any ideas?

If it is of use, here's the console full process:

```
D:\User Libraries\Desktop\Test>for %F in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "%F" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~nF_trimmed.mp4"

D:\User Libraries\Desktop\Test>ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "Test1.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "Test1_trimmed.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-91024-g293a6e8332 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.101 / 58. 19.101
  libavformat    58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
    date            : 2018
  Duration: 00:02:57.53, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 48706 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 48332 kb/s, 59.83 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 171 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Output #0, mp4, to 'Test1_trimmed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    date            : 2018
    encoder         : Lavf58.13.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 48332 kb/s, 59.83 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 171 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T06:59:14.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1211 fps=833 q=-1.0 Lsize=  124193kB time=00:00:19.98 bitrate=50911.9kbits/s speed=13.8x
video:123268kB audio:887kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.030864%

D:\User Libraries\Desktop\Test>ffmpeg -sseof -20 -i "Test2.mp4" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a copy "Test2_trimmed.mp4"
ffmpeg version N-91024-g293a6e8332 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 18.100 / 56. 18.100
  libavcodec     58. 19.101 / 58. 19.101
  libavformat    58. 13.102 / 58. 13.102
  libavdevice    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
  libavfilter     7. 21.100 /  7. 21.100
  libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Test2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
    date            : 2018
  Duration: 00:02:36.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 49260 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 48916 kb/s, 58.73 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
[mp4 @ 000001cf28f53740] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 000001cf28f53740] track 2: codec frame size is not set
Output #0, mp4, to 'Test2_trimmed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    date            : 2018
    encoder         : Lavf58.13.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 48916 kb/s, 58.73 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:2(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 195 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-05-05T07:02:30.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1225 fps=834 q=-1.0 Lsize=  125448kB time=00:00:19.98 bitrate=51429.4kbits/s speed=13.6x
video:124591kB audio:815kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.034254%
```